# why unicode data loading from dbf file with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, when BDE (borland database engine) is installed are wrong

Tags: vb.net, unicode

i write a code that show dbf file (foxpro 2.6 database) unicode record to datagridview

my connection string is:

Dim strCnnA As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\test.dbf;Extended Properties=dBASE III;"

dim ConnA As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

ConnA = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strCnnA)

---

when i load data to datagridview (vb.net) , It's all good

But when I installed the Borland Database Engine on my system (bde for other software I need) , the unicode data on my grid Becomes corrupted.

then

1- If you want to remove BDE, everything will be ok

2- if you rename BDE (for example BDEold) at bellow address , everything will be ok

C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Common Files\BDE

why ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think the Software change its file type like "Open With" maybe you can try to set your file to be open with "Your Database Only" so the file will not open in different type...